# Firebase OTP verification onVerificationCompleted not called

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I'm trying to set up OTP verification so when the user enters their phone number, I send them a pin code, the `onCodeSent()` is called and I receive the code pin, but the problem is when `onVerificationCompleted()` is called, I would like to move to another activity where the user can enter the code pin to verify but it is not called at all and I don't understand why. Any help would be appreciated guys, thank you.

```
val auth = PhoneAuthOptions
    .newBuilder(FirebaseAuth.getInstance())
    .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
    .setTimeout(60L,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .setActivity(this)
    .setCallbacks(object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        override fun onVerificationCompleted(p0: PhoneAuthCredential) {
            // here i want to get the smscode and send it over the next activity to verify
            // but this method is not called at all 
                                
            Intent(this,ChangePasswordActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("code",p0.smsCode)
                startActivity(this)
            }
        }

        override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException) {
            Timber.d("Firebase Exception ${p0.message}")
        }

        override fun onCodeSent(code: String, p1: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(code, p1)
        }

        override fun onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(p0: String) {
            super.onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(p0)
        }
    })
    .build()

PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(auth)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`onVerificationCompleted()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#onverificationcompletedphoneauthcredential) will only be called when the phone number has been verified without any input from the user. To do what you are trying, you should be sending your intent inside [`onCodeSent()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#oncodesentstring-verificationid,-phoneauthprovider.forceresendingtoken) instead.

Here is a rough flow of events (that are covered in detail in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone)):

1. Obtain phone number from user
2. Call `PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(auth)` (as you are already) to send the pin to the user
3. `onCodeSent()` is called, with the verification ID and a resending token.
4. Inside of `onCodeSent()`, create an intent to launch the "pin input screen" with the verification ID.
5. Get a pin from the user and then combine it with the verification ID by calling `PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, userInput)`
6. Use that credential to sign in the user using `signInWithCredential(credential)`.

```
val auth = PhoneAuthOptions
    .newBuilder(FirebaseAuth.getInstance())
    .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
    .setTimeout(60L,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .setActivity(this)
    .setCallbacks(object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
            // if here, phone number was verified automatically
            mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                 .addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */)
        }

        override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException) {
            Timber.d("Firebase Exception ${p0.message}")
        }

        override fun onCodeSent(verificationId: String, resendToken: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
            // if here, code was sent to phone number
            // open pin input screen
            Intent(this,ChangePasswordActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("verificationId",verificationId)
                startActivity(this)
            }
        }

        // we aren't using onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut, so it's omitted.
    })
    .build()

PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(auth)
```

Comment: The idea that i wanted to implement is that i want to compare both pin codes since i'm not using it to sign in user but to recover his password after getting a pin code in his number , in this case verification id is not the same as that pin code , i want to someone get the same code pin that was sent to the user and send it in intent extras and very in the other screen , is that people or my approach is not good thank you ?

Comment: You will never be told the raw pin as that defeats the purpose of out-of-bound authentication. You will only be given the verification ID which you send off with the user's input. You also cannot "recover" a user's password, only reset/change it - you should never store the user's password anywhere. To change the user's password, you should be able sign them in using the credential as above and then use [`updatePassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#set_a_users_password) assuming that you've linked the accounts.

Comment: let's assume a user forgot his password and is no longer able to access his account , in this case OTP is not worth and i should rather refer to email verification to reset passwod , by recover i meant reset as well  , is that still possible thank you ?

Comment: Please read the [documentation on resetting a user's password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email).

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link so to sum it up it is not possible to mainly reset user password using otp

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this problem but when I added my project to **google cloud console**, enable api services(google cloud console) and enable phone verification(google cloud console)
then **onVerificationCompleted** is working fine.
https://console.cloud.google.com/home

Comment: Which APIs you have enabled to make it work

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please enable this api in [Google play console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/playintegrity.googleapis.com).